# How can I convert byte array of Image (Taken from s3 ) into Image/Image object in C++ or C

Tags: c++, image

I want to convert the byte array into image or image object so that I can obtain image's height, width and data array.

Actually my Image is stored on `S3 (aws)`, So Image is taken from their in `golang` code and then passed to `node.js service` and further this `byte array` is passed to `C++ code`, and here (in C++) I need to convert this byte array into Image or Image object.

Please tell me some function by which I can find `image` out of `byte array` in `C++` or `C` . Actually I need image's height, image's width and it's data array.

So,anybody please suggest something to accomplish my task.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: Maybe you are looking something like Qt framework with it QImage and similar classes.

Answer (score -1):

Well, I can help you do it in golang, since that's where the picture is coming from. Just use the image package. Here's a full sample code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "image"
    "os"
    _"image/jpeg"
    _"image/png"
)

func main(){
    file, err := os.Open("image.png")
    if err != nil{
        log.Fatal("Image not read", err)
    }
    image, _, err := image.DecodeConfig(file)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("decode config error", err)
    }
    fmt.Println(image.Width, image.Height)
}
```

Hope this can help you.

Edit: in fact, I just found some c++ code to do this too, using CImg.

code:

```
#include "CImg.h"
using namespace cimg_library;
int main() { 

  CImg<unsigned char> image("someFile.jpg");
  int width = image.width;
  int height = image.height;

  return 0;
}
```

and the article : http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/45217/
I know you already have the file data read, but just play around with that library, I'm sure you'll come up with something. Also, if you're not actually using the image in node.js or golang, you might consider just passing around the image path, and opening it in c++.
cheers

Comment: Thanks for your reply but this is not what I am looking for , I just have a byte array of image not it's path, and that byte array is taken from S3 (AWS), and now I want to convert that byte array into image object in C++, So I need The way by which I can convert that byte array into Image object.